# Transformar linhas de dataframe em coluna python

Tags: python, dataframe

Eu tenho um data frame que contém 3 colunas. A primeira coluna é uma data, a segunda um grupo e a terceira a quantidade de registros para aquela data/grupo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A primeira coluna repete a data para cada grupo distinto e eu preciso que esta coluna seja única. É necessário que cada grupo se torne uma coluna, desta forma, terei uma linha para cada data distinta e as colunas (grupos) irão conter a quantidade de registros.

Seria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como proceder? Estou utilizando linguagem python.

Comment: Quando fizer uma pergunta não forneça código ou amostra de dados como imagens. Além de dificultar o leitor a copiar e colar as informações para testes também impede que usuários portadores de deficiências visuais possam o responder pois seus dispositivos assistivos não conseguem converter as imagens código ou dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tendo acesso aos dados, esta resposta será genérica, privilegiando assim a possibilidade de reproduzir a solução para casos similares.

Digamos que seu dataframe agrupado seja `df_grouped`

#### Passo 1: [reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

```
novo_df = df_grouped.reset_index()
```

#### Passo 2: [pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```
df_parcial = novo_df.pivot(index="Data", columns="Grupo", values="Numero Incidente")
```

#### Passo 3: [fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
df_resultado = df_parcial.fillna(0)
```

**Nota**: Pode fazer em um passo único:

```
df_resultado = df_grouped.reset_index().pivot(index="Data", columns="Grupo", values="Numero Incidente").fillna(0)
```

Comment: Acho que também dá para fazer direto com [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html): `pd.pivot_table(df, index="Data", columns=["Grupo", "Numero Incidente"], fill_value=0)` , mas não testei.

Comment: Quem votou negativo poderia esclarecer o porque? Eu produzo soluções de Data Analysis em python e não vejo nada de errado com essa resposta. Por favor se sabe de algo a mais informe nos ensine, mas não negative conteúdo correto porque não gosta do autor da publicação. Quando negativa baseado em julgamento emocional, ok seu desafeto perde 2 pontinho, mas em compensação toda as pessoas que no futuro chegarem a essa pergunta duvidarão da qualidade da qualidade da resposta escrita aqui.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, talvez tenha sido alguém que tenha a pergunta fechada com voto meu... Deixa pra lá... Continuarei contribuindo com que posso.